Larger audio files fail to buffer/play on iOS
I am using a VPS server to host audio files and most of the files work as expected (most files are up to 30 minutes long audio files), but when a audio file is longer, for example 1 hour and 30 minutes long then on iOS they play for about 10 seconds and not buffer at all any further (buffering can be visibly seen from the audio HTML element). The onstalled event will get triggered from frontend side every time it happens as well. The issue is consistent - meaning longer audio files never play as expected. I tried hosting the same larger audio files on dropbox and had no issues playing them then, so I am thinking it has to be something with the server settings. I even tried a dropbox file mp3 file, which was over 20 hours long and had no issues playing it, while the same file from my server would probably play it for about 10 seconds, get onstalled event.
Basically very simple web app that has just this HTML code won't play audio hosted on the server on iOS since it will fail to buffer files for some reason (but only with a bit longer files).
<audio src="path/to/file/on/the/sever" />

and this will work:
<audio src="path/to/dropbox/file" />

I have debugged this a lot, initially thinking it has do with my own frontend/backend code, but came to conclusion it has to do with the server itself since even the above example won't work.
I think it has something to do with the nginx.conf file to make it work, but I am not sure what to even change there, I have tried adding the following under the http block, but it made no difference
1. Enable sendfile, tcp_nopush, and tcp_nodelay:
===
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
===

2. Increase Buffer Sizes
===
client_max_body_size 100m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffer_size 4k;
proxy_buffers 8 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
===

3. Adjust keepalive settings:
===
keepalive_timeout 65;
keepalive_requests 100;
===

Currently my nginx conf file looks like this:
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;

        server_name website.com www.website.com;


       location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       }

       location /api {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
    }
}

From Node Express side the files are served like this:
   app.use(
      '/api/tracks',
      express.static('src/tracks'),
    );

The VPS server is decent that I am using with 8GB of RAM, 100GB SSD and 1Gbps Unmetered Bandwidth. I am completely out if ideas what to try anymore. It makes the app for iOS users unusable.
